# How do I fill an allocated 2D array with data from a file?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have the following piece of code in C:

```
#define LINES 40
int i,j,k = 0;

char **c;
char tmp;

// allocate key array memory
if( (c = malloc(LINES*sizeof(char*))) == NULL)
  printf("Error allocating memory\n");

for(i=0;i<LINES;i++){
    c[i] = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
}
```

I also have a file with data like this:

```
AsfAGHM5om
~sHd0jDv6X
uI^EYm8s=|
....
```

How can I fill the array allocated above with data from that file (for example using `fgets` or `fgetc`)?

Comment: There are 10 characters on each line, so you've not allocated enough space to treat them as (null-terminated) strings — you'd need at least 11 characters in each row of the array for that to be safe.  What should your program do if it encounters a line with only 9 characters before the newline?  With 11 or more characters?  What should happen if there are fewer than 40 lines?  If there are more than 40 lines?  What have you tried?  What were the problems you ran into?

Comment: hello @JonathanLeffler i've tried what u r seing above, as long as `malloc(16*sizeof(char))`. the problem is that i don't know how to assign to 2d array (c) the 10 characters lenght data. Also LINES is a predefined constant with value the number of file lines. I always know the number of file lines

Comment: Suppose you were reading into a 1D array — what would you do then?  Which function(s) would you use?  Adapting that to work with a 2D array is easy — though string assignment requires `strcpy()` rather than the `=` operator.

Comment: something like that for example?
`strcpy(c,fgetc(fp));`

Comment: `for(j = 0; j < 10; ++j) { c[i][j] = fgetc(fp); } fgetc(fp);/* drop newline */`

Comment: If every line of the file is exactly 10 characters then you could allocate a contiguous array

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i think you covered me! thx

Comment: @M.M in another aproach I just did that and also worked thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got constant length of the strings, like in your example, then you could define a macro with the `BUFSIZ` as the max length of the word. **Beware: don't forget to count also the** `'\0'` **character at the end of each string.**
In that case, the solution would look like this:

```
// create an array of strings
char ** array = (char **)calloc(LINES, sizeof(char *));

for (size_t i = 0; i < LINES; i++) {
    // allocate space for each string
    array[i] = (char *)calloc(1, BUFSIZ);
    // get the input
    fgets(array[i], BUFSIZ, stdin);
    // remove the '\n' character
    // from the end of the string
    array[i][strlen(array[i]) - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: although some comments above provided much help to me and i solved my problem by an approach similar to what M.M suggested your answer @Pet3rMatta is an elegant one and taught me calloc ;) thx